# Gps listener/receiver wakes up CPU

Tags: android, gps

From what I can see in the AOSP code, a `wakelock` is grabbed during `onLocationChanged` or when Android fires the intent to call the registered location receiver. So, you don't need to take a `wakelock` to do the processing, or at least you should take a wakelock for async operation done in `onLocationChanged` or if you start an intentService from the receiver and so on. Now my question: does the gps wake up the cpu? I mean: when the gps trigger is received by the OS the wakelock grants that the information can be processed, but before? Will the gps generate an interrupt to wake up the cpu? Even if you use the receiver version, it doesn't grant you that the gps wakes up the cpu, or is the listener/pendignIntent like the alarm of `alarmManager` and we can trust on it? Is it needed to grab a `wakelock` to keep the system on to receive the information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe you are thinking about it a little backwards.  Generally the app or the user will trigger the GPS, not the GPS triggering the wake lock.

### **Basically, if you ask for updates, you should get them (depending on a few things).**

**Criteria**
Whether the app keeps the GPS awake or not depends greatly on the [`Criteria`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html)

According to the [**`LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria c, PendingIntent i)`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method documentation:

> The location update interval can be controlled using the minTime
>   parameter. The elapsed time between location updates will never be
>   less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location
>   Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other
>   applications.

**Active Providers**

GPS and the Network Provider are considered "Active Providers".  Both take time to start up and get a new fix and consume battery.

The system will attempt to wake/use an **active** provider to meet your Criteria, and if you are using a `BroadcastReceiver`, then the `onRecieve` method is guaranteed to complete.

If you ask for the GPS every hour, the system should be waking the device, and running the GPS and checking it against your `Criteria` every hour assuming the provider is enabled.

> In case the provider is disabled by the user, updates will stop, and a
>   provider availability update will be sent. As soon as the provider is
>   enabled again, location updates will immediately resume and a provider
>   availability update sent.

**Additional Concerns & Triggers**

This is why they recommend considering additional triggers for listening like when the provider is enabled or disabled.  These can be combined with what **@danny177** mentioned such as the charging status and battery level.  Even the current Network State can matter here too.

> Providers can also send status updates, at
>   any time, with extra's specific to the provider. If a callback was
>   supplied then status and availability updates are via
>   onProviderDisabled(String), onProviderEnabled(String) or
>   onStatusChanged(String, int, Bundle). Alternately, if a pending intent
>   was supplied then status and availability updates are broadcast
>   intents with extra keys of KEY_PROVIDER_ENABLED or KEY_STATUS_CHANGED.

Finally you could also use the passive provider.  This will only give you an update if another apps wakes one of the active providers for you.

> If your application wants to passively observe location updates
>   triggered by other applications, but not consume any additional power
>   otherwise, then use the PASSIVE_PROVIDER This provider does not
>   actively turn on or modify active location providers

**Location Strategies**

Generally, you want to go from least accurate to most, lowest power to highest, etc..  For example, you could use the `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` to see if the user has move more than 100 meters.  Then if they have, request active location updates from the network provider to see if they are close to a specific location, then if that is true, use the GPS for something even more specific.

See: [**Location Strategies**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

> Determining which to use and trust is a matter of trade-offs in
>   accuracy, speed, and battery-efficiency.

**Google Play Services**

Finally, you cal also use Google Play Services as a location provider and piggyback on it's location updates.  This also gives you "free" geofencing and geocoding.

Comment: Summary: you don't need a wakelock according to your criteria, but if you are using the GPS and the provide for some reason goes down, you should take a wakelock to be "alive". Is it correct?

Comment: Sort of.  Basically: I think you already understand how you might use wake locks for async work in a receiver etc.  And for the most part, you would likely be fine without ever acquiring them.  Generally you will already be in the "long tail" of wakefulness when you receive an update.  Your larger concerns should be managing how often to ask for the kind of updates that would wake the device.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a wakelock to process locations received in `onLocationChanged()`.

**However background gps logging over a long time period might warrant the use of a wakelock**

Before turning on a wakelock consider the battery level, if the device is charging, when the wakelock will be released.

Universal Assumptions for background wakelock.

- Device is charging then wakelock.
- Device not charging and above N% then wakelock else release wakelock
- processing is done release wakelock.

***EDIT***

Please use a BroadcastReciver with your wake lock.

```
final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);

        registerReceiver(yourReceiver, theFilter);




private static BroadcastReceiver yourReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String s = intent.getAction();
            if (s != null) {
                if (s.equals(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_BATTERY_LOW)) {
                    cancelMyWakeLock();
                }               }
        }
    }
};
```

Remember to un-register in onStop()
 unregister code not shown.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "...might warrant the use of a wakelock". Would you mind explaining better to me? Is the wakelock needed or not?

Comment: @greywolf82  for the example of logging the GPS in a service might warrant means means might need.  So yes you may need a wakelock.  But before using a wakelock consider the battery state http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html  Think about is your app more important than saving the last bit of energy in the battery for an emergency phone call or to use the flash light?  Because a wakelock will drain the battery to 0 leaving the device useless until it can be recharged.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't undestand you. I know a wakelock can drain the battery but if I can't use a wakelock and the app stops, I think it's not a solution. So the point here it's not the collateral effect (the battery) but to understand if keep gps logging requires a wakelock. Once I understood this thing I can think about the other effects.

Comment: Then your app is more important than an emergency phone call you should use a wakelock.

Comment: So you are saying that to be sure the app works with 100% probability you should take a wakelock, but if you read the answer of pjco it seems that you shouldn't (with the exception of provider shutdown).

Comment: My experience actually is when the device is plugged in it doesn't sleep.  When the device is fully charged it doesn't sleep.  When the battery is low devices will definitely sleep.  I included some sample code for consideration to cancel the wakelock when the battery is low.